# Understanding a proof that $U(\mathbb Z/p^l\mathbb Z)$ is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

If $p$ is an odd prime, $l\in \mathbb Z^+$, then $U(\mathbb Z/p^l\mathbb Z)$ is cyclic, i.e., there exist primitive roots mod $p^l$.

**Background**:

**Theorem** $1$: $U(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ is cyclic.

**Definition**: We say that $a\in \mathbb Z$ is a primitive root mod $p$ if $\bar a\in  \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a generator of $U(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z).$

**Corollary $2$ to lemma $3$**: For an odd prime $p$ and $a: p\not|a$, the order of $1+ap$ is $p^{l-1}$ mod ($p^l$).

**Notations**: The fact that $a\equiv b \pmod c$ will be at times denoted by $a\equiv b(c)$.

Here is a proof of it, but I don't understand some steps in it.

By Theorem 1 there exist primitive roots mod $p$. If $g\in \mathbb Z$  is a primitive
root mod $p$, then so is $g + p$. If $g^{p-1} \equiv 1 (p^2)$, then $(g + p)^{p- 1} \equiv g^{p-1}+(p-1)g^{p-2}p\equiv 1+(p-1)g^{p-2}p (p^2)$. **Since $p^2$ does not divide $(p - 1)g^{p-2}p$, we may assume from the beginning that g is a primitive root mod $p$
and that $g^{p - 1} \not\equiv 1 (p^2)$.** (*Confusion $1$: Why does it matter that $g^{p - 1} \not\equiv 1 (p^2)$? Where is it used later on in the proof?*)

We claim that such a $g$ is already a primitive root mod $p^l$. **To prove this it
is sufficient to prove that if $g^n \equiv 1 (p^l) $, then $\phi(p^l) = p^{l-1} (p - 1)|n$.** (*Confusion $2$: Why is it sufficient? I think that we have to show that $g^{\phi(p^l)}\equiv 1(p^l)$, and that $g^t\not\equiv 1(p^l)$ for any $t| \phi(p^l)$*)

$g^{p-1}= 1 + ap$, where $p\not| a$. By Corollary 2 to Lemma 3, $p^{l-1}$ is the order
of $1 + ap$ mod $p^l$. Since $(1 + ap)^n = 1 (p^l)$ we have $p^{l-1}|n$.

Let $n = p^{i- 1}n'$. Then $\color{red}{g^n = (g^{p^{l-1}})^{n'}\equiv g^{n'} (p)}$
, and therefore $g^{n'} = 1 (p)$.
Since $g$ is a primitive root mod $p$, $p - 1 |n'$. We have proved that
$p^{l-1}(p - 1)|n$, as required. (*Confusion $3$: How does the red colored part follow?)*

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Confusion $2$ is clear to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Confusion 1: Why does it matter that $g^{p-1}\not\equiv1(p^2)?$ Where is it used later on in the proof?"*

> It is used in the claim "$g^{p-1}=1+ap,$ where $p\not|a$", which is necessary to apply "Corollary 2 to Lemma 3".

*"Confusion 2 is clear to me now."*

*"Confusion 3: How does the red colored part follow?*

> First, there is a misprint in the definition of $n'.$ It should be $n=p^{l-1}n'.$ This way, the first equality $g^n = (g^{p^{l-1}})^{n'}$ becomes clear. The less obvious $(g^{p^{l-1}})^{n'}\equiv g^{n'}\bmod p$ is due to Fermat's little theorem: $g^p\equiv g\bmod p.$